# Modular Pattern vs Prototype - Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns, server, prototype

I am working in `Nodejs`. I had worked in `modular pattern`. It is easy and simple to code.

**Note**

> My colleague told Prototype pattern is best approach for Nodejs and Modular pattern is slow.

### My Code Sample

```
module.exports = {

                      get : funcntion(){
                        //stuff
                      },

                      set : function(){
                        //stuff
                      }
                  }
```

#### Question

What pattern would be the best for realtime web application or generally an application context with Nodejs?

Comment: "My colleague told Prototype pattern is best approach for Nodejs and Modular pattern is slow." - this is kinda wrong assumption, is he/she relying on facts (benchmark) ? The pattern choice really depends of the individual case.

Comment: @RistoNovik That's why I posted a question, To get the real fact

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me put my thoughts here:

```
// vinoth.js
var Vinoth = function () {};

Vinoth.prototype.log = function () {
  console.log('Hello Vinoth');
};

module.exports = new Vinoth();

// app.js
var vinoth = require('./vinoth.js');
vinoth.log();
```

Simple `module` pattern

```
//vinoth.js
module.exports = function () {
  console.log('Vinoth');
}

// app.js
var vinoth = require('./vinoth.js');
vinoth();
```

From what i `understand` is:

`Prorotype pattern` helps you with `inheritance` and extending the functionality and there is only one instance of functions in a memory irrespective of the number of objects. `Vinoth.prototype.log` is added to `prototype` and this function is not created again for a new objects.

In `Modular pattern`, for each object a new instance of function is created in memory but helps you with `encapsulation`.

Comment: @karthick.k: very difficult to say, if you have complex objects playing around go with prototypal inheritance. modular pattern is good to go with a single instance playing around with a group of functions. The loading time would certainly vary depdending upon your object size.

Comment: Plus 1 , Thanks a lot for the information, Prototype is faster than modular.

Comment: In the above example I could not see the advantage of using the prototype pattern there with pre creating the instance `module.exports = new Vinoth();`, why not use the `module.exports = Vinoth();` ?

Comment: @RistoNovik: You can't see in the above example, but certainly when your object becomes complex, it makes a lot of sense to go with prototype. Why would you need a function instance in every instance of the object, when you can share the instance?